# Subdivision glitch, what's going on?

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

[image]

I'm sure there is only one node at each turning point.
Some edges cannot be rounded properly, why?

---edit---

[image]

I think I know what the problem is...that surface has been opposite,
but I still don't know how to fix it.

---edit---

Okay, [Shift]+[N] is the solution.

Comment: Hello, try to recalculate the normals (Shift N), merge the vertices (M > Merge by Distance), check inner faces? Or please share your file

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have inverted normals, select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>